# How to change this code to list post titles of all the post on Blogger in format YYYY.MM.DD <title> and chronological order?

Tags: javascript, list, blogger

I like to show my titles of posts on a specific page. It is more effective to get know what author have written than scroll all pages or navigate using archive widget.

I found code (code is below) for generate list that sort post titles alphabetically but I like to show titles in chronological order. There is lot of code example about this but they are outdated. They doesn’t work anymore after some changes in blogger platform.

How to change code to get post titles in chronological order and in format YYYY.MM.DD  ?

```
<div>
    <ul id="postList12"></ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var startIndex = 1;
    var maxResults = 150;
    var allResults = [];
    function sendQuery12() {
        var scpt = document.createElement("script");
        scpt.src = "/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&callback=processPostList12&start-index=" + startIndex + "&max-results=" + maxResults;
        document.body.appendChild(scpt);
    }

    function printArrayResults(root) {  
        //Sort Alphebetically
        allResults.sort(function(a, b)
        {
            var a_string = a.children[0].textContent ;
            var b_string = b.children[0].textContent ;

            if(a_string < b_string) return -1;
            if(a_string > b_string) return 1;
            return 0;
        })

        var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
        for (index = 0; index < allResults.length; index++) {
            elmt.appendChild(allResults[index]);
        }
    }

    function processPostList12(root) {    
        var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
        if (!elmt)
            return;

        var feed = root.feed;

        if (feed.entry.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < feed.entry.length; i++) {
                var entry = feed.entry[i];
                var title = entry.title.$t;
                var date = entry.published.$t

                for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++) {
                    if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                        var url = entry.link[j].href;
                        if (url && url.length > 0 && title && title.length > 0) {
                            var liE = document.createElement("li");
                            var a1E = document.createElement("a");
                            a1E.href = url;
                            a1E.textContent = title + " (" + date.substr(0,10) + ")";
                            liE.appendChild(a1E);
                            //elmt.appendChild(liE);
                            allResults.push(liE);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (feed.entry.length >= maxResults) {
                startIndex += maxResults;
                sendQuery12();
            } else {
                printArrayResults();
            }
        }
    }
    sendQuery12();
</script>
```

Code is copied from here: https://dansator.blogspot.fi/2015/10/general-alphabetical-list-of-posts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `sort` method from the code. remove the following :

```
//Sort Alphebetically
allResults.sort(function(a, b){
        var a_string = a.children[0].textContent ;
        var b_string = b.children[0].textContent ;

 if(a_string < b_string) return -1;
 if(a_string > b_string) return 1;
 return 0;
   })
```

**Your code should be**

```
<div>
<ul id="postList12"></ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var startIndex = 1;
var maxResults = 150;
var allResults = [];
function sendQuery12()
{
   var scpt = document.createElement("script");
   scpt.src = "/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&callback=processPostList12&start-index=" + startIndex + "&max-results=" + maxResults;
   document.body.appendChild(scpt);
}

function printArrayResults(root)
{  
   var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
    for (index = 0; index < allResults.length; index++) {
         elmt.appendChild(allResults[index]);
    }
}

function processPostList12(root)
{    
  var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
   if (!elmt)
      return;

   var feed = root.feed;

   if (feed.entry.length > 0)
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < feed.entry.length; i++)
      {
         var entry = feed.entry[i];
         var title = entry.title.$t;
         var date = entry.published.$t

         for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++)
         {
            if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate")
            {
               var url = entry.link[j].href;
               if (url && url.length > 0 && title && title.length > 0)
               {
                  var liE = document.createElement("li");
                  var a1E = document.createElement("a");
                  a1E.href = url;
                  a1E.textContent = title + " (" + date.substr(0,10) + ")";
                  liE.appendChild(a1E);
                  //elmt.appendChild(liE);
                  allResults.push(liE);
               }
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      if (feed.entry.length >= maxResults)
      {
         startIndex += maxResults;
         sendQuery12();
      } else {
         printArrayResults();
      }
   }
}
sendQuery12();
</script>
```